# Gradle could not start your build.I dont what happend but android studio is showing this error.Yesterday it wasnt there but today I dont what happend

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jetbrains-ide

I have started Android development and this is my first stackoverflow question. I have tried deleting as well as making a new fileHash file. I have aslo tried deleting .gradle file. I am not able to understand, can you guys please help?

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
   > Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Program Files\AndroidStudioProjects\EarthquakeReport\.gradle' when creating directory 'C:\Program Files\AndroidStudioProjects\EarthquakeReport\.gradle\6.7.1\fileHashes'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.initialization.exception.InitializationException: Gradle could not start your build.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:48)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:848)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:563)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:621)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:786)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:772)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:563)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:621)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:786)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:772)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:563)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:621)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:786)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:772)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:563)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:621)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:786)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:772)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:563)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:621)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:289)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:146)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:78)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:48)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.createRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Program Files\AndroidStudioProjects\EarthquakeReport\.gradle' when creating directory 'C:\Program Files\AndroidStudioProjects\EarthquakeReport\.gradle\6.7.1\fileHashes'
    at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:313)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:75)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:95)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.<init>(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.VirtualFileSystemServices$BuildSessionServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache(VirtualFileSystemServices.java:329)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:846)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: i really had missing dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is some files are missing, don't delete the Gradle file and any inbuild files and classes.

If you need this project try to undo what you did, or try to recover revert it back if your project is connected with the version controller.

**Note:** For best practice, try to debug and understand the problem then solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much I remade the project and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t delete gradle files. Why did you delete those files?
However At this point I’d delete the whole project and recreate a new one copy/pasting your code.